# How to optimize the loading of images

Tags: jquery, performance, load

I would be interested to hear if anyone has any suggestions on how best to speed up the loading of this page. Or atleast give the impression of a faster loading. I find the loading graphic lasts a little too long. I'm not a big fan of the jQuery lazy load plugin.

http://www.peterclarke.com.au/project-type/architecture/

Comment: when possible you can use sprites to reduce the call for images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install the pageSpeed extension. This extension gives you suggestions that you can use to increase your website's speed (cookie-less domain, sprites, etc).

**Example**

[image]

Another good tool is [webpagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org). With this tool you can test your website speed in various browsers at various locations in the world.

**Example**

[image]